# Is it better to store access token for one hour or refresh it every call

Tags: node.js, spotify, access-token

I have a webapp that only read data from Spotify API, so I don't need user to login, have a specific scope, etc.

For now, I use the Client Credentials Flow. When I get the access token I store it in DB with the date of emission.
Then for each call, I get this access token from DB, and if it's older than one hour I get a new one and replace it.

Is it the best solution to do?
Or is it better to use the Authorization Code Flow and refresh token for each call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any request consumes resources and time and the common practice is to get token and use it until expiration time.

Comment: Ok so what I did by storing the access token in DB and checking each time if it is expired is the good practice?